# Textbox not clearing after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this chat room on my website, where the user types their message into a textbox and when they press enter (or the send button),  jQuery takes the data from the textbox, disables the textbox, sends the data to the file `send.php` where it is then processed and put into the database, and then it should clear and undisable the textbox once it successfully runs through the PHP script. What is happening is the data is being submitted and it runs through the script (sends the data to the database successfully) but the jQuery is not clearing and undisabling the textbox. 
Can someone explain to me what is wrong?

**jQuery**:

```
$('#formSend').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var textArea = document.getElementById('styled');

    if( textArea.value != "" ) {

        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        $('.expand').prop("disabled", true)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'send.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (formData) { //put data in parentheses when coming back
                alert("Success");
                $(".expand").val('');
                $('.expand').prop("disabled", false);

                if( formData["banned"] == 1 ) {
                    var rel = confirm("You have been banned.");
                    if (rel) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Your message must be longer than 1 (one) character.");
        $('#styled').focus();
    }
});
```

**send.php**:

```
<?php

include("../config.php");
session_start();


$msg           = strip_tags( $_POST['msg'], '<b></b>' );

if( $msg == "" ) {
 exit("There is no message.");
}
$username      = $_SESSION['USER'];
$date          = new DateTime();
$formattedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = :username");

$stmt->execute(array(":username" => $username));

$row = $stmt->fetch();

$userID = $row['id'];

$checkBanned = $db->prepare('SELECT banned FROM users WHERE username = :username');
$checkBanned->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username
        ));
$banned = $checkBanned->fetch();

if( $banned['banned'] == "yes" ) {
    $return = array('banned' => 1);
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}

try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `chat-messages` (userID,msg,date) VALUES (:userID, :msg, :date)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':userID' => $userID,
        ':msg' => $msg,
        ':date' => $formattedDate
    ));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Here is the form too, if needed.

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" name="formSend" id="formSend" />
     <textarea id="styled" class="expand" name="msg" placeholder="Your Message Here" onfocus:"setbg(\'#e5fff3\');"required></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="banned" value="no" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="send" />

  </form>
```

Comment: Is the success callback fired?

Comment: as @A.Wolff asked, can you see the alert message "Success" ?

Comment: Why do you need to clear the field if you're just going to reload the page?

Comment: Looks like you aren't returning JSON from server if user not `banned`

Comment: I am not getting the `alert("Success");`, which was how I was checking to see if the function was being performed.

Comment: @Locke You could have really made your question more clear because as i read it, your issue was regarding textbox not beeing disabled/resetted, not regarding the success callback beeing not called

Comment: I didn't realize that was my problem until now, sorry.

Comment: @Locke You could just bind error handler to ajax method. This should help you to get a better idea what's going wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you have not sent any responce if user is not banned and message is stored successfully.

If "success" is not being alerted then that is the problem.

Try this,

```
try { $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `chat-messages` (userID,msg,date) VALUES (:userID, :msg, :date)'); $stmt->execute(array( ':userID' => $userID, ':msg' => $msg, ':date' => $formattedDate ));
$output = "success";
 } catch(PDOException $e) { $output =  $e->getMessage(); } 
finally{
echo  json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: Ya because he is setting datatype to JSON and server isn't returning JSON, this is how i see it too

Comment: The PHP Version I am using is 5.4, so finally isn't accepted.

Comment: You can echo json in try and catch saperately.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are refreshing the page afterwards, that could make the form to autocomplete to the previous value, try this:

```
  <form autocomplete="off" action="send.php" method="post" name="formSend" id="formSend" />
     <textarea id="styled" class="expand" name="msg" placeholder="Your Message Here" onfocus:"setbg(\'#e5fff3\');"required></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="banned" value="no" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="send" />
  </form>
```

Comment: I was only refreshing afterwards if the PHP script found that the user was banned.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to reload the page (which should actually happen, if you dont prevent the submit event from beeing triggered in the ajax callback by event.preventDefault()) you have to reset the form by doing something like $('#formSend').reset();

Furthermore, there is no disabled='false', you need to remove the attribute: $('.expand').removeAttr('disabled');.

By the way, it is good habit to save selector you need more than one time ;)

Comment: OP is using `$('.expand').prop("disabled", false);` which is the preferred method to set any boolean attribute as `disabled` one

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like:

```
$('.expand').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: How would that affect whether it clears the input field?

Comment: even if the textarea is disabled, it is still possible to set its value, so this will not help i think

Comment: It makes no sense to set disabled to false. The HTML specification sets that as long as the atttribute disabled is set the input is indeed disabled.

Comment: I agree, but this does not solve the problem of clearing the input, does it ?

Comment: It is kind of sad that by pointing an error in a script, even if it is not the complete solution you get a down vote :-(